# 2nd function not working whan activate the plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, hook

Hello i am creating a plugin when i activate the plugin it create attribute size and colors in this first code i am creating

```
global $wpdb;
// attributes parameters
$wpm_attributes = array(
    array('label' => 'Size',  'name' => 'size','type' => 'select',),
    array('label' => 'Color', 'name' => 'color','type' => 'select',)
);
//create default attributes
foreach ( $wpm_attributes as $attr ) {
    $attribute = array(
        'attribute_label'   => $attr['label'],
        'attribute_name'    => $attr['name'],
        'attribute_type'    => $attr['type'],
        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order'
    );
    if( !term_exists( $attribute ) ){
        $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );
        delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
    }
}
```

it working 100% fine after it i creating terms the code is

```
global $wpdb;
$size_terms = array(
    array('label' => '2-XL',       'slug' =>  '2-xl'),
    array('label' => '3-XL',       'slug' =>  '3-xl'),
    array('label' => '4-XL',       'slug' =>  '4-xl'),
    array('label' => '5-XL',       'slug' =>  '5-xl'),
    array('label' => '6-XL',       'slug' =>  '6-xl'),
    array('label' => 'L',          'slug' =>  'l'),
    array('label' => 'M',          'slug' =>  'm'),
    array('label' => 'S',          'slug' =>  's'),
    array('label' => 'XL',         'slug' =>  'xl'),
    array('label' => 'XS',         'slug' =>  'xs'),
    array('label' => 'XXL',        'slug' =>  'xxl'),
    array('label' => 'Custom Size','slug' =>  'custom-size')
);
// //insert default trems
foreach ( $size_terms as $term ) {
    //if( !term_exists( $term['label'], 'pa_size' ) ){
        wp_insert_term( $term['label'], 'pa_size', array( 'slug' => $term['slug'] ) );
    //}
}
```

but on first activation the plugin just adding attribute size and color and term function not working after that when i reactivate plugin again the in 2nd time terms added why it  not togather working on 1st activation?

Comment: Any one here? please helpme to fix it

Comment: are you try this function or not register_activation_hook()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to add data on plugin activate, always use this function [register_activation_hook()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) in your main plugin file.

Now try this in your code

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Your Plugin Name
  Plugin URI: http://Plugin URI
  Description: Plugin Description
  Author: You
  Version: 1.0
  Author URI: http://
 */

function function_name(){
    global $wpdb;
    // attributes parameters
    $wpm_attributes = array(
       array('label' => 'Size',  'name' => 'size','type' => 'select',),
       array('label' => 'Color', 'name' => 'color','type' => 'select',)
    );
    //create default attributes
    foreach ( $wpm_attributes as $attr ) {
        $attribute = array(
            'attribute_label'   => $attr['label'],
            'attribute_name'    => $attr['name'],
            'attribute_type'    => $attr['type'],
            'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order'
        );
    if( !term_exists( $attribute ) ){
        $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );
        delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
    }
  }

  // Your Second Data Entry
  $size_terms = array(
      array('label' => '2-XL',       'slug' =>  '2-xl'),
      array('label' => '3-XL',       'slug' =>  '3-xl'),
      array('label' => '4-XL',       'slug' =>  '4-xl'),
      array('label' => '5-XL',       'slug' =>  '5-xl'),
      array('label' => '6-XL',       'slug' =>  '6-xl'),
      array('label' => 'L',          'slug' =>  'l'),
      array('label' => 'M',          'slug' =>  'm'),
      array('label' => 'S',          'slug' =>  's'),
      array('label' => 'XL',         'slug' =>  'xl'),
      array('label' => 'XS',         'slug' =>  'xs'),
      array('label' => 'XXL',        'slug' =>  'xxl'),
      array('label' => 'Custom Size','slug' =>  'custom-size')
  );
  // //insert default trems
  foreach ( $size_terms as $term ) {
    //if( !term_exists( $term['label'], 'pa_size' ) ){
        wp_insert_term( $term['label'], 'pa_size', array( 'slug' => $term['slug'] ) );
    //}
  }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'function_name');
?>
```

**Note:** the best practice is write this code at top of the file, but not neccessry

Hope this will help you

Comment: How can i add terms prices? i mean product price is $50 and we set price XL $20 when we select it on front page so it should $50 + $20 = $70 how to define prices for evry size?

Comment: why not but give me some time